# Adding an attribute programmatically in Magento 2.1

Tags: product-attribute, magento-2.1, catalog, setup-script

I am creating a product attribute for sorting which will be int type :
where I am getting following error:

> PHP Fatal error:
>   Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute'
>   not found in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code
>   /Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php:57

Here is my `Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'sorting_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Sorting Attribute',
                'input' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => 0,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code in module.xml file to this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module"  setup_version="1.0.0">
     <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Replace your code with this code in InstallData.php.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        /* assign object to class global variable for use in other class methods */
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
         $setup->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);


        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
       */
       $eavSetup->addAttribute(
         \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
       'sorting_attribute',
       [
       'type' => 'int',
        'backend' => '',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'Sorting Attribute',
        'input' => 'text',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => '',
        'global' => 1,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'default' => 0,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique' => false,
        'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable,grouped',
        'group'=> 'General'
       ]
      );






       $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change: `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL` to `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL`.

```
     //'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL, <= Remove this line
     'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
```

Comment: after updating your comment in my code m getting :     Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The configuration parameter "formElement" is a required for "sorting_attribute" field.

Comment: Now, your setup script run successfully? Or still throw new exception?

Comment: yes I did setup:upgrade still getting the same error

Comment: this error is coming while clicking on Products->catalog-> add new product tab

Comment: `setup:upgrade` still getting error or not?

Comment: Yes it showing still the same error!!

Comment: I have just installed the new attribute successfully on Magneto 2.1.2 version. Please clear your Magento Cache and go to table `setup_module` remove your `Vendor_Module`. And try to run setup upgrade again. Go to `eav_attribute` table to check.

Comment: in eav_attribute it was coming , frontend also showing option but while add new product tab in admin is showing this error

Comment: This is because we need to add custom attribute to product form component: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/customize_product.html